# Jquery Hide OK Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, hide

I work With Jquery and I have Dialog with two buttons `[ OK, Cancel ]`

my code is

```
 $("#test").dialog({
            modal: true,
            minHeight: 600,
            minWidth: 550,
            buttons: {
                OK: function() {

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

Sometimes I need to hide `OK` button (only view Permission)

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $("#test").dialog({
            modal: true,
            minHeight: 600,
            minWidth: 550,
          buttons: [{
                        text: "Ok",
                        id:"okid" ,//by this id set now you can do all operation base on this id
                        click: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                          }
                       },
                        {
                                  text: "Cancel",
                                  click: function () {
                                      $(this).dialog("close");
                                   }
                                }]
        });
```

for hide ok button now

```
$("#okid").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector to identify the button and call `$(selector).hide()`

For example this should work with jquery ui

```
$('.ui-button:contains("Ok")').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTIONS
In buttons section you can find 2 button -- one is Ok , second one is Cancel ...
You can not remove ok portion depending upon your condition / requierement.

Like if not-logged in you can load a different modal ...
If logged in you can load another dialog....

SUGGESTIONS
In buttons section you can find 2 button -- one is Ok , second one is Cancel ...
You can not remove ok portion depending upon your condition / requierement.

Like if not-logged in you can load a different modal ...
If logged in you can load another dialog....

```
var checking = '<?php  if($UserId == "")echo '0'else echo 1; ?>';
if(checking == 1){
      // load a dialog
}else{
    // load a different dialog
}
```